# TFS 2008 connection via internet

Tags: tfs

I install an TFS 2008 on Server 2008 machine. TFS is working very well in localusers but We can not reach our projects via internet. Developers who are outside the office could not reach TFS. How can I handle this??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to expose TFS ports (usually 80, 8080, and 8090) to the internet so external users can connect.  Have you done this yet?

If your external developers are all working at one remote site, you may want to look into using TFS Proxy as well to cache source control items at their location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Teamplain?

If this is for access to source control I don't think Teamplain would help. But to access work items etc it may.

Will need to open the neccessary ports etc.